# What is the Hessian w.r.t. to matrix X of this quadratic function?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, quadratics, matrix-calculus

I am stuck in finding the Hessian w.r.t. to matrix $X \in R^{m \times n}$ in the following :

$$\frac{1}{2} ||AXB-C||_F^2$$ 
where $A \in R^{l \times m}$ and $B \in R^{n \times o}$

I got the first order derivative (gradient):

$$A^TAXBB^T-A^TCB^T$$

but I am stuck with the Hessian. I guess it should be something like $A^TABB^T$ but there is a problem in the dimensions as both $A^TA$ and $BB^T$ are square matrix but of size respectively $m$ and $n$ so I don't see how to multiply them.

I was wondering if it wouldn't imply tensor product but I am not so sure

Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 1):

To continue with your calculation, let's find the differential of the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 G &= A^TAXBB^T - A^TCB^T \cr
dG &= A^TA\,dX\,BB^T \cr
}$$
From here, there are two ways to proceed to the hessian: tensors or vectorization.

Let's introduce the isotropic fourth-order tensor ${\mathcal E}$ whose components can be written as the product of two Kronecker deltas. 
$${\mathcal E}_{ijkl} = {\delta}_{ik}\,{\delta}_{jl}$$
Let's also introduce the single-contraction (denoted by juxtaposition) and double-contraction (denoted by a colon) products between tensors.
$$\eqalign{
{\mathcal C} = {\mathcal A}{\mathcal B} &\implies {\mathcal C}_{ijklmn} = \sum_{p} {\mathcal A}_{ijkp}{\mathcal B}_{plmn} \cr
{\mathcal C} = {\mathcal A}:{\mathcal B} &\implies {\mathcal C}_{ijmn} = \sum_{k,l} {\mathcal A}_{ijkl}{\mathcal B}_{klmn} \cr
}$$
Use these notations to find the tensor hessian (${\mathcal H}$).
$$\eqalign{
dG &= A^TA\,dX\,BB^T = A^TA\,{\mathcal E}\,BB^T:dX \cr
{\mathcal H} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial X} &= A^TA\,{\mathcal E}\,BB^T \cr
}$$
Or, we can use vectorization to calculate a matrix hessian ($H$).
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vec}(dG) &= {\rm vec}(A^TA\,dX\,BB^T) = \Big(BB^T\otimes A^TA\Big)\,{\rm vec}(dX) \cr
H = \frac{\partial\,{\rm vec}(G)}{\partial\,{\rm vec}(X)} &= BB^T\otimes A^TA \cr
}$$
The two results are very similar, simply interchange $({\mathcal E}\leftrightarrow\otimes)$ and reverse the order of the factors.

Comment: ⊗ is the Kronecker product, right ?

Comment: Yes, it is the Kronecker product.